# How to get item set in an asynchronous POST response in reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have two related tables via strapi `order_detail` and `orders`. i create an `order_detail` first and then use its response to create `order` on `Submit`

```
  const createOrder = ()=>{
    const arr=[];
    
    JSON.parse(ordered_products).map(item => {
      

       return postData('http://localhost:1337/Order-Details',{"ProductName":item.Title,"OrderedProductQuantity":item.qty}).then(data =>{
          arr.push(data.id.toString())
          localStorage.setItem('id_details',JSON.stringify(arr));
        } 
        
        )
    }) 
}
```

**Submit function**

```
onSubmit={(values, { setSubmitting }) => {
         createOrder()
  
         postData('http://localhost:1337/orders',{"Address":values.Address,
        "PhoneNumber":values.Phone,
        "CustomerName":values.Name,
        "order_details":localStorage.getItem('id_details')
      }).then(data => {
        console.log(data)

      })
  
      }}
```

`POST` request is called before `createOrder()` sets localStorage, `localStorage.getItem('id_details')` is never available and this probably due to how non-blocking javascript works.

How can i wait for localStorage to be `set` and `get` it in the subsequent call?

```
"order_details":localStorage.getItem('id_details')
```

Comment: Is createOrderDetail  and createOrder the same? Only see createOrderDetail's definition.

Comment: oh thats a typo, but yes its the same thing. will update it

Comment: Do not use Localstorage at all and work with the post data. createOrder().then( (details) => { ... })

Comment: @madflow that raises a `TypeError: createOrder(...).then is not a function`

Comment: You will have to do some more work... Basically - you are currently writing async code and expecting synchronous execution. For example: Array.map is not save for async code. Use Promise.all() instead.

Comment: @madflow i was able to get it to work with your direction. If you can, you may go ahead and provide it as answer such that i may accept it.